# "Attributes.inc" file not found

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have been using the headers provided in `include\llvm` and `include\llvm-c` to try and make my own compiler. However, whenever I try to compile, I get this error. There is no `llvm/IR/Attributes.inc` in my files nor any LLVM project I have seen. I get this error:

```
In file included from ./headers/llvm/IR/Function.h:26:
In file included from ./headers/llvm/IR/Argument.h:19:
./headers/llvm/IR/Attributes.h(74,14):  fatal error: 'llvm/IR/Attributes.inc' file not found
    #include "llvm/IR/Attributes.inc"
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Attributes.inc file is generated using tablegen program, which takes Attributes.td domain specific file as input. i suggest you use llvm-config utility to properly get include path of your built llvm.

Comment: I have not seen tblgen on any tutorial or documentation. Do you recommend any tutorials?

Comment: i presume you are using the llvm source and building it (instead of llvm-dev packages and headers files), so during the build process it automatically generates all those files and binaries also the "llvm-config" binary contains all the related information. i would suggest you go through https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html for building llvm binaries process and https://pauladamsmith.com/blog/2015/01/how-to-get-started-with-llvm-c-api.html for compiling your c/c++ code using llvm part.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. I got it fixed by adding the following line to the relevant `CMakeLists.txt`

```
> add_dependencies(<Module Name> intrinsics_gen)
```

Answer (score -3):

make install-llvm-headers may help u