# What is the correct way to include llvm library in CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, llvm-ir

I recently installed LLVM 7, and tried to include the necessary files to start a project using llvm library in CLion. 
However, it complains that some files are not found.

My CMakeLists.txt file has the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(TestCmake)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

link_directories(llvm/build/include/) # linked wrongly..
include_directories(llvm/llvm/include/) #linked wrongly.

set(BUILD_2 main_2)
set(SOURCE_FILES_2
        # testing. llvm files.
        tests/codegen_tests/fac.cpp
)

add_executable(${BUILD_2} ${SOURCE_FILES_2})
```

I know the way am linking is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.
I let it like this, because CLion can find the defined libraries (so I can see when I call functions of the libraries that don't exist, and if it's available I get a pop-up).

Am currently getting the following error when I run the project:

```
   In file included from c4/llvm/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Module.h:23:0,
                 from c4/tests/codegen_tests/fac.cpp:1:
c4/llvm/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Attributes.h:74:38: fatal error: llvm/IR/Attributes.inc: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/main_2.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main_2.dir/tests/codegen_tests/fac.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/main_2.dir/tests/codegen_tests/fac.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:109: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main_2.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main_2.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:121: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main_2.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main_2.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:153: recipe for target 'main_2' failed
make: *** [main_2] Error 2
```

The project structure is shown here [image: Project Structure]

Any help on this, is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As described in the comments to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615541/attributes-inc-file-not-found), the file `llvm/IR/Attributes.inc` is **generated**, so it isn't located under llvm *source* dir. Assuming you have llvm **installed**, you need to call `include_directories` for directory under installation prefix (something like `llvm/install/include/`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev. Thanks for your comment. 
I tried that I I get undefined reference errors, such as:
`undefined reference to llvm::Value::setName(llvm::Twine const&)`.

Also, I tried including **build**, **install**, **llvm** (without build or install). but I get generally the same kind of errors.

if I use make (we have a makefile for it), it works via the terminal. But I want to run and debug using CLion.

Comment: As usual, "undefined reference" error is resolved by linking with a proper library. In CMake linking is performed with `target_link_libraries` command.

Comment: I have been trying to see how I will use `target_link_libraries()` with llvm. 
Can you give an example code of how it will be used? I don't understand which files/binaries to link it against.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and the [LLVM documentation:](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) solved my issue.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.3)
project(TestCmake)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

# Set your project compile flags.
# E.g. if using the C++ header files
# you will need to enable C++11 support
# for your compiler.

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

# Now build our tools
add_executable(simple-tool tool.cpp)

# Find the libraries that correspond to the LLVM components
# that we wish to use
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)

# Link against LLVM libraries
target_link_libraries(simple-tool ${llvm_libs})
```